# How to check for duplicate values in the same dataframe column and apply if condition by dropping the row based on frequency?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**Dataframe :**

| name | Location | Rating | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ali | Nasi Kandar | 1 star | 1 |
| Ali | Baskin Robin | 4 star | 3 |
| Ali | Nasi Ayam | 3 star | 1 |
| Ali | Burgergrill | 2 star | 2 |
| Lee | Fries | 1 star | 3 |
| Abu | Mcdonald | 3 star | 3 |
| Abu | KFC | 3 star | 1 |
| Ahmad | Nandos | 3 star | 2 |
| Ahmad | Burgerdhil | 2 star | 3 |
| Ahmad | Kebab | 1 star | 10 |

Here is the sample data set. The logic would be:

**1st condition**: if the **name** has duplicate values, check the **frequency** and see which one is higher, drop the row with lower **frequency**

**2nd condition**: If no name duplicate (e.g:Lee), keep the row

**3rd condition**: Rating is the same (e.g: Abu), keep the first value

**Desired Output:**

| name | Location | Rating | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ali | Baskin Robin | 4 star | 3 |
| Lee | Fries | 1 star | 3 |
| Abu | KFC | 3 star | 1 |
| Ahmad | Kebab | 1 star | 10 |

*Any of you guys know how I do this in **python pandas** or **pyspark**?*

I got into troubles checking for duplicates and also applying probably the "if condition" to this dataframe

Comment: Could you show what have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: For `Abu` need `3` because first value (and also max)

Comment: That is true Abu should be Mcdonalds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyspark solution. You can use `row_number` over an appropriately ordered and partitioned window, and get the rows with a row number of 1.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'rn', 
    F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('name').orderBy(F.desc('frequency')))
).filter('rn = 1').drop('rn')

df2.show()
+-----+------------+------+---------+
| name|    Location|Rating|Frequency|
+-----+------------+------+---------+
|Ahmad|       Kebab|1 star|       10|
|  Abu|    Mcdonald|3 star|        3|
|  Lee|       Fries|1 star|        3|
|  Ali|Baskin Robin|4 star|        3|
+-----+------------+------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and last sorting index:

```
df = (df.sort_values(['Frequency','Rating'], 
                     ascending=[False, True])
        .drop_duplicates('name')  
        .sort_index())
print (df)
    name      Location  Rating  Frequency
1    Ali  Baskin Robin  4 star          3
4    Lee         Fries  1 star          3
5    Abu      Mcdonald  3 star          3
9  Ahmad         Kebab  1 star         10
```

Comment: Thx you are brilliant. Hmm I see one error over here because the first row is wrong, the location should be Baskin Robin with the highest frequency